iOS navigation bar overlaps status bar on landscape dismiss
I have an app almost entirely built with Xcode Interface Builder and no code with the exception of the overrides of supportedInterfaceOrientations to fix the UIViewControllers orientation to either portrait or landscape. The app is composed of two view controllers:

The first one is embedded in an UINavigationController and has a navigation bar. This view controller's orientation is portrait-fixed.
The second one is landscape-fixed and presented modally on Fullscreen. It has a button to go back to the first VC by unwind segue.

When the button in the second view controller is pressed, the VC slides out of the window and once the animation is over the status bar appears over the navigation bar, partially overlapping it (NOTE: the layout fixes itself when the status is pressed). You can view the problem in the following video: https://imgur.com/FIBoszM
The following screenshots shows the "actual" (left) and "expected" (right) behaviours.


Why is this happening?

Can you post a minimal reproducing example project, at GitHub for example, so we can try doing what you're doing? You've described it very clearly but it would be great to have an actual project to try it with. Otherwise we don't know how you are setting this whole thing up (in the storyboard etc.). Thanks!

@matt Sure! here you go: ios-navbar-test

Yeah, I see it. The real source of the problem is that the status bar goes away in landscape and comes back in portrait. If you change the presentation mode to a cross dissolve you can actually see the status bar going away before the presentation. And it doesn't come back until after the dismissal.

I see, is it possible to avoid the "layout jump" caused by the status bar in the transitions? I'd really appreciate any ideas or guidance on how to solve this issue.

Sorry, I think the best solution is don't do that. Apple really doesn't want you forcing an orientation change, and over the years has closed the door on most of the ways we used to be able to do it. This is just another one.

@matt There are legitimate use cases for that approach. For example, see Netflix.

@Grodriguez I don't say there are not legitimate use cases. My own apps do it. But there are fewer and fewer situations where it works cleanly, and the OPs situation is one where it does not work cleanly, because of the timing of the way the status bar goes away and comes back and the interaction of the navigation bar height with the status bar.

But this is straighforward code, 99% of which is generated by IB. The status bar goes away in landscape mode because this is the default in iOS. The animations are also the default ones supplied by the system, nothing custom here. It's hard to understand why this wouldn't work :-/.

There are two possible solutions depending on your preferences.

You can show/hide navigation bar visibility for your app by setting this boolean value true or false inside Info.plist file:


<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
   
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>



You can control navigation bar appearance directly by using navigation bar's translucent property. That would fix the issue of the app view being framed underneath the navigation / status bar.
You can use it like this:


self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Or if you need to hide and then show it. You can use something like this:
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}

For older iOS versions you may need to try something like this:
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Side Note: You may also need to check with Xcode that you are placed your app components inside Safe Area widget. That would prevent this issue without any further changes.

Not sure how this addresses the question.
